# Using "Refactor Fields" to Change Precision

Tags: qgis

I am trying to use the Refactor Fields tool to change the precision of one of the Real fields in a shapefile from 0 to 4. I simply change the precision from a 0 to a 4 under the Fields mapping in the tool. After the tool runs, the field has been changed from a precision of 0 to a precision of 5, not 4. Not only that, it has changed the precision of every real number to a precision of 5 even those which had a precision greater than 5. Even if I don't change anything but just run the tool, it changes every real number to a precision of 5. Is there something more I need to do?

Comment: It looks like a bug.

Comment: I thought it was just me doing something wrong. If it is a bug, does it need to be reported somewhere?

Comment: I got same results. It is not normal. I can't see any option to fix it.

Comment: @BruceWiland - You say you _"change the precision from a 0 to a 4"_, and then later you say _"changed the precision of every real number to a precision of 5 even those which had a precision greater than 5"_. I may have misread but can you expand on this please? If the field initially had a precision of 0, how could there be values with a precision greater than 5 for them to be changed?

Comment: There were some Real number fields that had a precision of 0 and some fields that had a precision of 6. I tried to change only the ones that had a precision of 0 to 4. After running the Refactor Tool, all of the Real numbers had a precision of 5, both the ones that I changed from 0 to 4 as well as those which had a precision of 6 but which I hadn't tried to change. In fact, if you run the Refactor Tool without making any changes, the tool changes all Real numbers to have a precision of 5.

Comment: I don't know if it means anything, but if you look at Fields in the Layer Properties, the Type Name had been changed from "Real" to "double" for every "Real" type name. It also changed the "id" field from type "qlonglong" and type name  "Integer64" to type "Qstring" and type name "string".